# Error “The timezone provided to builtin function todatetimeoffset is invalid.”

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In SQL Server 2008 R2 the function TODATETIMEOFFSET shows the following error:

> The timezone provided to builtin function todatetimeoffset is invalid.

In some installations of SQL Server 2008 R2 the function works (same database and same code)

This is the code I’m using, it is part of a stored procedure:

```
-- table to contain every office timezone offset in minutes
DECLARE @mOfficeOffsetsT TABLE 
                         (
                             [OfficeCode] VARCHAR(20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS primary key,
                             [OffsetMinutes] INT
                         );    

 INSERT INTO @mOfficeOffsetsT ([OfficeCode], [OffsetMinutes])
     SELECT         
         [OfficeCode], [OffsetMinutes]    
     FROM
         [dbo].[GetOfficeOffsets]();  -- GetOfficeOffsets function get all offices offsets in minutes, for example: -180

DECLARE @mNow DATETIMEOFFSET;
SET @mNow = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(); 

SELECT           
    NTF.[NotificationId], 
    NTF.[ScheduleDate],    
    NTF.[AppointmentId]     
FROM
    [Notification] NTF    
INNER JOIN
    [Appointment] AP ON NTF.[AppointmentId] = AP.[AppointmentId]  
INNER JOIN
    @mOfficeOffsetsT OO ON AP.[OfficeCode] = OO.[OfficeCode]      
WHERE           
    TODATETIMEOFFSET(AP.[AppointmentDate], OO.[OffsetMinutes]) <= @mNow;
```

Notification table columns:

```
[NotificationId] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[ScheduleDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[AppointmentId] [int] NOT NULL, 
.. other columns ..
```

Appointment table columns:

```
[AppointmentId] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
[OfficeCode] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
[AppointmentDate] [datetime] NOT NULL ,
.. other columns ..
```

My function “GetOfficeOffsets” doesn’t seem to be the problem, because if I hardcode @mOfficeOffsetsT table rows the error remains.

The data in the tables seem to be ok.

I have reproduced the error in:

- SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM
- SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1

  - SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2
  - SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3

SQL Server and database collation I'm using: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

The OS does not seem to have influence:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (production) >> get the error
- Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard (testing) >> works well
- Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (dev) >> works well
- Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter (dev) >> get the error

OS Region and Language settings does not seem to have influence.

Does anyone know what may be causing this strange error?

Comment: Are you completely sure that your OffsetMinutes are not outside of the range -840 to 840?

Comment: Data which we can use to replicate the issue will be really important here.

Comment: @LuisCazares Yes I'm completely sure, there are two offices and in both of them time zone is "-03:00" (OffsetMinutes = -180).

Comment: Can this be related? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6c38a5cd-8b18-40b6-a5cb-56c45abdc2fd/todatetimeoffset-fails-only-when-reading-smallint-offset-value-out-of-a-table?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 0):

This error also causes if you pass incorrect format to second parameter of `TODATETIMEOFFSET()`.

[In the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/todatetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) it says,

```
TODATETIMEOFFSET ( datetime_expression , timezoneoffset_expression )
```

The second `parameter:timezoneoffset_expression` should be like `'+10:00'` format.

I had same error when I was giving `'+10'` instead of `'+10:00'`. Check your second parameter might help you.